What prevents a sphere from being wrapped by an elastic sheet with bending and stretching allowed?
I know it's impossible to find an isometry between a sphere and a piece of plane. But if stretching is allowed, what topological or geometrical properties prevent an elastic sheet from smoothly transforming to a sphere? Or in other words, why isn't there a diffeomorphism between a sphere and some quotient space of ${\rm I\!R}^2$ (like the diffeomorphism between a torus and ${\rm I\!R}^2$/$\mathbb{Z}^2$)?
Edit:
I searched the web. The similar questions are all about whether a sphere is diffeomorphic / homeomorphic to a plane or whether a sphere
with some points removed is isomorphic to a plane. I know the answer to the first one is no because a diffeomorphism/homeomorphism preserves compactness. And here no point of the sphere is removed. Since a 2-torus, a compact surface, is diffeomorphic to $\rm I\!R^2$/$\mathbb{Z}^2$, why can't a sphere be diffeomorphic to some quotient space of $\rm I\!R^2$?
Edit 2: I was pointed to the link. I don't think it solves my problem. But I think one answer in the link may give some clue for this: The homotopy groups are a sort of quantification of a higher order connectedness.

You can show that they are not homeomorphic. See here for exmpale: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370640/proving-2-sphere-is-not-homeomorphic-to-plane

@AdamRubinson Of course a compact space is not homeomorphic to a noncompact one. The linked question does not address at all the crucial point in the OP, that one is asking about a quotient space of the plane. At the very least, now some algebraic topology may come into play.

You are mistaken: sphere is homeomorphic to a quotient space of $R^2$ (one can even find a local diffeomorphism from the plane onto the sphere).

@MoisheKohan can you please point out the homeomorphism or diffeomorphism to me? or can you please point me to the references? Thanks!

If $C = \Bbb R^2 \setminus B(\mathbf 0, 1)$, the complement of the open disk of radius $1$ about the origin, then $S^2$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2 / C$.

@PaulSinclair I see. Essentially, it can be thought of as identifying all the points "outside" the unit disk into one point. Thanks. May I ask whether a diffeomorphism like this exists?
